# Java Drag and Drop to native os

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, java-native-interface

I've been looking around for some time and have yet to be able to find any libraries or information for Java on how to drag lets say an ImageIcon onto a Windows folder and get the path as to where you "dropped" the ImageIcon. I'd really like a platform independent solution that works across OSX/linux/Win, but at the very least would like a windows implementation. Has anyone done this before, is there a project that has a library to do this? If not could I get direction(websites) as to how one would go about developing the C++ code to do this, if at all possible I'm assuming would have to be done through JNI.  Is it even feasible?

I have a good amount of experience with java, python and perl, but limited exposure to C/C++, which is why I'm hoping there is already a library or some code out there to do this, if not though, I'm more than willing to get my hands dirty.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 6, then see [this page about JDK6 Drag and Drop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/dragndrop/index.html).

Comment: I hope it's finally usable in JDK6 because I used the JDK 1.4 version, which was fixed fromt he earlier version, and it was still a nightmare.